# How to check if the user entered "yes" or "no" and nothing else?

Tags: java

I would like to find out if there is a way to make a program not continue unless the user enters *"yes"* or *"no"* ONLY. Normally when I use the `answer.equalsIgnoresCase(" ")` if I enter the word *"dog"* it acts as *"yes"*. Can anyone help?

Currently I have it like this:

```
System.out.println("\nDo you want to add another item? (Yes/No)");
answer = br.readLine();

switch (answer) {
    case "YES":
    case "Yes":
    case "yes":
    case "y":
        continue;

    case "NO":
    case "No":
    case "no":
    case "n":
        break;

    default:
        System.out.println("\nWarning: You need to enter Yes or No!!. Do you want to enter another item? (Yes/No)");
        answer = br.readLine();

        if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
            continue;
        } else
            break;
}
```

Output:

> ~~~~~WELCOME~~~~~
>   Enter item code
>   #Kv1
>   Enter item description
>   peas
>   Enter item weight
>   2.2
>   Enter item price
>   $3
>   Do you want to add another item? (Yes/No)
>   dog
>   Warning: You need to enter Yes or No!!. Do you want to enter another item?(Yes/No)
>   dog
>   Item List:
>
> 1)
>   Item code: #Kv1
>   Item Description: peas
>   Item Weight in grams: 2.20
>   Unit Price: $3.00

Comment: Surely there is a bug. Show us your codes

Comment: 'dog' should not have worked in place of 'Yes'. Looks like you have a bug.

Comment: Yes, there is a way to compare strings in Java.  No, we can't tell you what's wrong with code you're not showing us.

Comment: The break is just breaking out of the `switch` statement. You need to break with a label or set a condition variable and test it outside the `switch` to break out of an enclosing `for` or `while` loop. But you should provide a working program if you want detailed answers.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ here it is

Comment: You can't be showing the full code (assuming the code you have compiles, that is) since the use of `continue` would throw a compile error if the given code was just in a method on its own. Can you paste the full code (or at the very least, the full code from the relevant method.)

Answer (score 0):

When you enter "dog," you enter this block of the switch

```
default:
        System.out.println("\nWarning: You need to enter Yes or No!!. Do you want to enter another item? (Yes/No)");
        answer = br.readLine();

        if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
            continue;
        } else
            break;
```

When you then enter "dog" again, `answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")` evaluates to `false` and it breaks from the loop. That's why "dog" is behaving strangely; your default case ensures that any two back-to-back "wrong" inputs will fail. Since we can't see the outer loop, it's hard to solve your exact problem... but rethink your switch block logic. Since you're trying to make it behave like a `while` loop, maybe redesign it:

```
    System.out.println("\nDo you want to add another item? (Yes/No)");
    String answer;

    // Assuming br is some instance of a Scanner
    while( !(answer = br.nextLine()).equalsIgnoreCase("no") ) {
        if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
            //Do your logic for yes
            System.out.println("Hooray, you entered yes...");
            System.out.println("Do you want to add another item? (Yes/No)");
        } else {
            System.out.println("\nWarning: You need to enter Yes or No!!. Do you want to enter another item? (Yes/No)");
        }
    }

    // Print the results…
    System.out.println("Hooray, you entered no...");
```

Comment: The `break` in the `else` branch breaks the `switch`, not the outer loop (which we sadly don't know yet).

Comment: Yes, you're right. You can see from his output example, though, that the second input is given before it loops again (evidenced by seeing the warning message, but not the "Do you want to add more...?" msg). I think the problem is probably that the print command immediately follows the switch block, and so it will print no matter what once it breaks from the switch block. Of course, we can only speculate until we see the whole thing...

Comment: I could also imagine that his loop has some kind of "strange" termination condition, but let's wait for the full code/runnable example.